# Which is better way to implement edit - listview with edittext or table layout with edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

Need to implement edit in runtime. Which one is the best way to achieve it.
Edittext in Listview or dynamic table layout(inflating row xml) with edittext

Update:

My listview contains 7-8 view(Text view) in a list item. On click edit button using view switcher changed textviews to edit text. To get the entered value in edittext listening onfocuschanged. It brings very slow performance. Any better way to achieve it?

Update:
 If my listview have 100 list items. Each item having 7-8 edittext. Need to listen all the edittext focuschange. My app hangs. What should i do?

Comment: listivew in edittext thats my opinion

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you want to do ?

Comment: If i want to have more than 8 Edittext in a single list item i need to have implement onfocus change listener for 8 edittext. Feeling performance slow on adding new items to list. Any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` within `ListView` can cause you great grief down the lane given that views are recycled in listview.

Say you have tapped on the second row in a listview where all item rows contain a edittext and you have set adjustResize in your AndroidManifest.xml; after the soft keyboard pops up, the focus goes into the first view that can accept the focus which in this case will be the first edittext (row) of your listview. Yes, you can tap again on the desired edittext to regain focus. But it is an annoyance nevertheless. If you set adjustPan, then I have seen the the problem does not exist as such; if I recollect correctly, you cannot scroll down all the way to the end of your list. Again, another annoyance.

I'd suggest, you go with a `ScrollView` if the number of items in the list are less. I have been trying to solve this for the last couple of days - I ended up doing this - I replaced the edittext's with textview's in the listview; tapping on the textview would bring up a dialog fragment that contains the edittext.

Have you looked into the concept of a ViewHolder to keep a reference to the items of the listview? That should solve your multiple focus listener problems.

Comment: Thanks @Vino. Unfortunately it is a dynamic list. And need to have multiple selection.

Comment: Even i set android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants". I couldn't able to select the view with edittext.